# How to pass connectionstring value from Unity3d to a classlibrary with ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, connection-string, class-library, configurationmanager

I created a class named "DB" in a ClassLibrary named "DBLayer" to connect a database named "LinguisticsDB". When I implement this ClassLibrary into another project, it can connect its App.config file via "connectionStrings" tag. But I need to access my ClassLibrary from Unity3d help to some kind of file like App.config. I need a step-by-step guide.
On the other hand, I do not know where should I import App.config file?

My DB class into DBLayer:

```
        public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinguisticsDB"].ConnectionString;
        static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        static SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;

        public static DataSet GetData(string query)
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            connection.Close();
            return dataSet;
        }
```

My App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LinguisticsDB" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-NORA1IP; Initial Catalog=Linguistics; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I tried to import App.config file into my Unity project inside Scripts folder; but it did not work.

Comment: what exactly is the question? Maybe how to [deserialize a an XML file](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: the app config file is more a c# thing than a unity thing.  Have a read up on it

Comment: I need to pass connection string values from Unity to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using static connection string. This is awful but it worked.
I changed this

```
public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinguisticsDB"].ConnectionString;
```

to this

```
public static string connectionString = @"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=myDatabase; Integrated Security=True;"
```